# Mac os : no such file or directory found error even though file exists

Tags: macos, certificate, keytool

I am trying to import certificate to jks
My command looks like this

Keytool -importcert -file "/Users/sachin/certificates/g3.cer" -keystore "/Users/sachin/certificates/jks/my.jks" _alias "myalias1"

When I run the above in terminal, I see

-bash Keytool -importcert -file "/Users/sachin/certificates/g3.cer": No such file or directory .

When I do ls or Cd,  I can see those files and navigate through the directories .
This is driving me crazy . Appreciate any help.
New to Mac OS

Comment: That error message suggests that bash is interpreting the entire string as the command name, rather than `Keytool` being the command name and `-importcert` etc being arguments to it. How exactly are you running this command?

Comment: Running from bash

Comment: But how exactly? Are you typing it in character by character? Pasting it in? Is it in a script? *Some*thing is weird about what's going on, but without more detail I have no idea what that something is. BTW, while typing in a command, you can press Tab to autocomplete file paths, so if you use that to build the path you can at least tell if bash is interpreting it the same way you expect.

Comment: I built the command in notepad then pasted it in bash

Comment: And the path is definitely correct,  I would have checked atleast 50 times,  wondering if there is anything wrong with syntax or bash itself

Comment: More likely something with Notepad or how it's being pasted. Try `echo [paste the command here] | LC_ALL=C cat -ve` (be sure to type the "echo" and "| LC..." parts yourself, don't paste them) and see what it prints.